# Is it safe to remove the extra local disk after upgrading to Windows 10 version 1803?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1803

I upgraded Windows 10 to version 1803 recently, and I discovered that I now have an extra local disk (drive D) which only has about 500 MB space.

After checking in the Disk Management interface, I found that it is a small partition at the front of my drive. I remember this is where Windows stores a copy of the previous version and it should not be visible.

**Is there anything wrong with my installation? Should I delete this partition?**

## Update

Based on discussions on SU and other sources from the Internet, this is a minor issue with the Windows update, and the partition can be hidden easily. Please check the answer section.

Comment: @Ramhound the first one is a good find. I literally spent about ten minutes performing advanced searches within the superuser.com domain for a duplicate, because I couldn't believe that nobody else had mentioned this since version 1803 was released. When all of my searches turned up empty, I posted an answer.

Comment: @Run5k Seen this question at least 5 times since April 30th. It was of course answered all the way back in 2012.  It’s worth while having a specific question/answer for this problem though.  At least justifiable.

Comment: @Ramhound I suspected as much, but Google was apparently letting me down. I found posts on Ten Forums, Microsoft Answers, and a few other domains, but couldn't find one here. Trust me, it wasn't for a lack of effort.

Comment: A favorite stuff like that 

Comment: While other posts focus on how to hide/remove this partition, my question was if the upgrade is successful, because that partition is supposed to remain hidden if the update succeeded.

Comment: @davidshen84 - Does not change the fact this question is a duplicate, since the duplicate also deals with successful upgrade to 1803, as evident by the fact this question keeps on being asked.  The events leading to the cause of this behavior as not so far identified by anyone who asked the question.  I can confirm it does not always happen.  My own sample size is four physical machines and 3 virtual machines.  In 0 cases did this behavior happen on those machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is there anything wrong with my installation? Should I delete this partition?*

No, there is nothing wrong with your Windows 10 installation, and you don't need to delete that partition.  This has happened on a semi-regular basis following the upgrade to Windows 10 version 1803.  Apparently, some systems are seeing this extra recovery partition with an assigned drive letter in the aftermath, usually with a label that says `Healthy (OEM Partition)`:

[image: Disk Management]

---

However, the Microsoft forums describe a relatively simple procedure to hide this partition:

> 1. Open Start.
> 2. Search for Command Prompt.
> 3. Right-click the result and select Run as administrator.
> 4. Type the following command to start DiskPart and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>: **diskpart**
> 5. Type the following command to list all the volumes and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>: **list volume**
> 6. Type the following command to select the volume in question (for example, X) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>: **select volume X**
>      (Important: Proceed
>      with caution, and replace "X" with the letter that appears in the
>      newly created partition.)
> 7. Type the following command to remove the letter and hide the partition in question and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>: **remove letter=X**
> 8. Use the exit command to close DiskPart.
>
> After completing these steps, the drive will disappear from File
>   Explorer, but it'll continue to be present on your computer.
>
> According to reports, Microsoft is aware of the issue, and the company
>   may release a cumulative update to automatically address this problem.

Sources:
[New disk partition after 1803 update](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/new-disk-partition-after-1803-update/c16f232d-1f9c-402a-838a-7d8a4ee05bb6?auth=1) 
[Windows 10: Extra drive (partition) after update 1803](https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/110255-extra-drive-partition-after-update-1803-a.html)

Comment: So, everything is fine with my installation/upgrade. it's just M$ forgot to hide the partition for me, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.