# Drive undetected after restart during windows update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I’ve been having a multitude of problems with my pc at the moment which is why I’ve been trying to use the windows update assistant to update windows (I'm trying to update to Windows 10 1903 - currently using Windows 10 1809)
However, the problem is that every time the device is restarted during the update, my C drive is the only drive that is not detected. The only way for it to be detected again is to turn the computer off then back on. (I have just error checked the drive and no errors were found - though the check went from having 35 minutes remaining to being finished in one second) This stops the update and the update cleans its files and puts my pc back to how it was. I’ve tried to update with only the C drive connected but with the same result.
This also happens if I try to restore my system (keeping files and data but removing apps)
As of writing this I am about to create instillation media and try that way.

Edit:
I made an ISO image and started an update from that, it updated to around 30% and then restarted all fine. The restart was fine as it was done within the desktop. Now my pc is ‘Working on Updates x%” with the normal message of this will take a while and your pc will restart several times. But every time the pc is restarted from this point, the drive is not detected after the restart. There is nothing I can do about it.

Edit #2:
As expected, the above happened. When the desktop loaded up, the Windows 10 Setup tool prompted me with:
We couldn't install Windows 10. We've set up your Pc back to the way it was...
The error message is:
0xC1900101-0x2000C
The instillation failed in the SAFE_OS phase with an error during APPLY_IMAGE operation.

Comment: This is a symptom of hardware trouble not operating system trouble. Trying to upgrade your OS on faulty hardware has a high risk of making things worse.

Comment: @Appleoddity yes but it only happens during windows update or windows restore, it never happens during a reboot or a restart caused by the user. Also this is a relatively new SSD and works fine normally.

Comment: Which update did you install?  Creating an installation disk and using that instead of using the Reset functionality will not solve your problem.  Please provide this information in the body of your question before you attempt to do anything.  I have a couple of ideas but it requires no changes to be made for me to verify them.

Comment: @Ramhound just edited the main body regarding to which update. Also edited about the drive error check.

Comment: Do you have any external drives connect to your system?  There is a bug with the upgrade to 1903, which requires you to disconnect any external drives, otherwise, the upgrade will fail.  1903 won't be installed through Windows Update (or that's supposed to be the case) if external drives are connected. *What are the attributes of the drive in question?*

Comment: No I removed all drives as you cannot start the update with them plugged in. I made an ISO image and started an update from that, it updated to around 30% and then restarted all fine. The restart was fine as it was done within the desktop. Now my pc is ‘Working on Updates x%” with the normal message of this will take a while and your pc will restart several times. But every time the pc is restarted from this point, the drive is not detected after the restart. There is nothing I can do about it.

Comment: Which is the reason I am interested in the attribute of the drive.  You should verify it's not listed in Disk Mangement.

Comment: What are you asking me to do @Ramhound ?

Comment: To use the appropriate diskpart command to retrieve the attributes of the drive.  [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1370499/how-do-i-know-that-a-drive-that-is-not-labelled-recovery-is-actually-the-recov/1370578#1370578) is an answer that explains how to do that.

Comment: @Ramhound ok so here are the attributes:
Partition 4
Type    : ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7
Hidden  : No
Required: No
Attrib  : 0000000000000000
Offset in Bytes: 645922816

Comment: @Ramhound my second edit to the main body should also give some more information