# Can I delete old System Reserved partition after changing mbr to gpt (legacy to Uefi)?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, mbr, gpt, boot-partition

I used a third party software to change form mbr to gpt and it created an new system partition ( I think). It says (EFI System Partition) and the old one is still there labeled *System Reserved* and it says (Basic Data Partition).
Does that mean that I can delete the older system partion or is it still necessary?

Comment: The System Reserved is required.  It absolutely should not be deleted.  The partition should be less than 500 MB in size.  [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1370499/how-do-i-know-that-a-drive-that-is-not-labelled-recovery-is-actually-the-recov/1370578#1370578) answer explains the rules for the partition.

Answer (score 0):

My advice : Do not delete this very small partition.

In Windows 10, the System Reserved partition contains the Windows
recovery environment.
This is not connected to the disk format, either GPT or MBR.

If you remove it, you lose the possibility to recover Windows
in case of error.
You will then need to fix boot errors and others by booting from
a Windows boot media.

This small partition can be a life-saver in emergency.

Comment: **The System Reserved partition doesn't actually contain the WinRE image since it's only suppose to be 16 MB.**  WinRE would be contained on the Recovery partition and must be a minimum of 500 MB.  [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1370499/how-do-i-know-that-a-drive-that-is-not-labelled-recovery-is-actually-the-recov/1370578#1370578) is the rules for the recovery partition.  The EFI partition is 300 MB.  Easy enough to determine by checking the partition type and see if it's equal to `de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac`.  **I agree the partition should be left alone.**